# Build Failed: unable to find ojdbc .jar file

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, jdbc-odbc

When I run the project I get an error:

> C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\project\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1007:
>   Warning: Could not find file
>   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar to
>   copy. BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Previously Database I used was Oracle but now I want use Mysql Server. I've already changed the code accordingly, also put mysql connector inside libraries.
Where have I stuck? Why it is giving error concerning oracle driver even if mysql server used?

P.S.
Server used: Apache Tomcat 7.0
Netbeans version: 7.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably still have references to the old jar in Netbeans' build script. Right click on your project, select Properties, and look under the Build section for any reference to the old jar.

You can also edit the ant build script manually. The file path is given in the error message your provided.

Answer (score 0):

You probably still have references to the old jar in Netbeans' build script. Right click on your project, select Properties, and look under the **library** section for any reference to the old jar.